# how to connect webcamera to jsp?

Tags: jsp

I have an jsp page and i want to connect my webcam to jsp page, but i cant have a idea how to connect them. so please help me, so i can access my webcam on my jsp page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there are two ways:

- You can use the [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-device/) `<device>` tag;
- You can use RIA interfaces with [Java](http://www.surveyor.com/support/webcam32help/java.html) Applets or [Flash](http://thulasiramsoft.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/simple-webcam-capture-demo-for-flex/);

I would use the second method because the first one is at its begging.

It's pretty easy to a webcam Applet in your page, but the problem is what will you do with the sent stream and where will you route it?

Regards.